# Unknown error (0xfffffffe) while impersonating in C#

Tags: c#, elevated-privileges, impersonation

**C# Impersonate Error**

Hello, wanted to create an application that would give me privileges to install applications with an user that has such accesses. It's important that the user with elevated privileges would be log onto from inside the application and thats what i've been trying to do but it seems it doesn't work.

**So what i did was used this library:**
http://impersonation.codeplex.com/

So i could impersonate admin user from within the application.

Everything works fine until i try to actually run the application with elevated user access, if i don't log in with admin user, then my application simply gives me exception where it says that **access is denied**, when however i log in with user that has these privileges, it gives me **unknown error exception**, so im wondering why is that.

**However, when i try to run file that my current user has access to, it runs just fine.**

Now there probably isn't any workaround here unless i **run this application as service**, but i just want to **make sure**.

**Application GUI**

[image: Application GUI]
<sub>(source: [upload.ee](https://www.upload.ee/image/1680202/1.png))</sub>

**Error Snapshot**

[image: Error Snapshot]

**Full source:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Diagnostics;

using Iuf.Network.Authentication;

namespace AccessPool
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Impersonation UserAccess;
        Process FileProcess;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserAccess = new Impersonation(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, "ametikool.local");

            try
            {
                UserAccess.ImpersonateUser();
            }
            catch (Exception ImpersonateException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ImpersonateException.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Access granted!");
                btnOpenFile.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog FileDialogObject = null;

            try
            {
                FileDialogObject = new OpenFileDialog();
                FileDialogObject.ShowDialog();
            }
            catch (Exception FileDialogException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(FileDialogException.ToString());
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                txtFilePath.Text = FileDialogObject.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                FileProcess = new Process();
                FileProcess.StartInfo.FileName = txtFilePath.Text;
                FileProcess.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception FileProcessException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(FileProcessException.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is quite a good question, remove "go to school" part :) It may indeed frighten people so they do not read further:)

Comment: I have no idea how i would ask that question without "go to school" part, as the school's users structure is pretty important part of it.

:)

Comment: Yes, -2 is certainly an unknown error.  You are probably not the first student that tried to hack the machine, you won't find much help here.

Comment: Hans Passant, first of all it wouldn't matture if i am a student or not, as it doesn't have anything to do with my programming motives nor skills, and if i would want to hack a machine then i would've just reset bios chip and would've booted it from linux. Sorry but i can't help myself but to feel offended by such comment.